# How to keep the Execute SQL Task inside event handlers out of the parent transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using SQL transaction in SSIS where I have an *`Execute SQL Task`* to Start, Commit and Rollback my transaction. All transaction tasks are inside a *`Sequence Container`*. I am perfoming error handling at package Level events and logging errors to a separate database. The problem that I am running into is when any component fails it jumps to the event handler but when the transactions roll back, it rolls back error logging as well.

Error logging is taking place within *`Execute SQL Task`* inside *Events handler*

Is it possible to explicitly specify on my *`Execute SQL Task`* that it is not part of transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest that you use the SSIS transaction handling. Set TransactionOption to Required on the Sequence Container, and to Supported on the child tasks. Set the TransactionOption to NotSupported on the On Error event handler, so that it acts outside of the Sequence Container's transaction.

Hope this helps,
Peter